Validity of Bertrand's theorem for a self-interacting system
We know that in classical mechanics, a particle of mass $m$ orbiting in a given central-force potential $V$ will satisfy the following eom:
$$\frac{d(m\dot{r})}{dt}-mr\dot{\theta}^2+\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}=0$$
and then the Bertrand's theorem says that only when $V$ corresponds to inverse-square law or Hooke's force we get closed orbits even if initial condition on the particle deviates more than slightly for circular orbits.
In general, the particle itself can influence the form of potential $V$ we are working with. For e.g., $V$ satisfies Poisson equation for the case of Newtonian gravity:
$$\nabla^2V = -4\pi G \rho (x).$$
The $\rho$ could correspond to some localized distribution of particle and source which will satisfy the 1st equation. Thus, when we allow mass $m$ to influence the potential, will it be possible to obtain some potential allowing stable orbits?

Particle does not influence the potential $V^$ that appears in the equation for its motion. That potential is due to all the other particles. The potential $V$ in Poisson's equation is net potential, or potential due to specified $\rho$; it is not the "experienced potential" $V^$ in the equation of motion for the particle.

Is it really so? when we write the lagrangian (density) of the entire system, we need the lagrangian for particle 1 + particle 2 + field $V$ and their interaction. If we extremize the full lagrangian we get the same V appearing in both eom of particles and Poisson equation. V = 1/r we used in the theorem is for a static isolated particle/sphere, but we have two particles which are interacting with one another, it is not clear why V should be 1/r even in this case - the boundary conditions are different.

There is no action/lagrangian for point particles which would work with single function $V$, one has to differentiate potentials/fields due to each particle, and any one particle experiences field of the other particle only. Net $V$ is singular at all point particles, so it cannot be used to get equations of motion.

Net $V$ may be enough only if it is regular, e.g. when particles have finite charge density (non-zero volume). Lagrangian formulation of such extended particles is not very well developed and has not made it into textbooks.

Point particles will give divergent results yeah. But is there no perturbative approach for extended objects?

In non-relativistic theory, all forces obey Newton's 3rd law, so the body can't act on itself, so its contribution to $V$ is irrelevant to motion of its center of mass, whether the body is point or extended. In relativistic theory (EM theory), extended bodies can act with self-force on themselves (increased/decreased inertia, Lorentz-Abraham force), and for central force motion, this can lead to unstable orbits (in case of retarded forces). Relativistic theory of extended bodies is hard and obscure field, see e.g. approximate treatment by Lorentz, Abraham and later works re charged sphere.

In relativity, extended body has infinite number of degrees of freedom, and there is no simple model of a compact body known that could be easily analyzed.
